# CODI ViewAccessScoped session behavior

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, session-state, codi

I have a prototype small application built using JSF 2.0 with Primefaces 3.4.2., Spring 3 and Hibernate 4

For ManagedBeans I am using scope as `@ViewAccessScoped`. I have noticed that while doing pagination in datatables and selection of rows, same view session is used for all sessions, i.e. if I select 3rd row in datatable using Chrome and if I open another browser session using Firefox or Internet Explorer, I can see the same session with 3rd row being selected of datatable.

What could be the reason for this? How can I make sure that different sessions should be created for different users (sessions)

This is how it is defined in ManagedBeans

```
@Named("myMB")
@ViewAccessScoped
public class EmployeeController implements Serializable {
```

Package name for `ViewAccessScoped` is

```
org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.ViewAccessScoped
```

Any insight or help on this are highly appreciable.

Comment: Can you provide the package name of @ViewAccessScope?

Comment: @Thor I have included package name for ViewAccessScoped in question.

Comment: The `[spring]` tag on the question is confusing and creates only more questions. Are you managing beans by Spring or by CDI?

Comment: @BalusC Excuse my ignorance in this, I have applicationContext.xml for scanning beans and the following in `faces-config.xml` `<application>
  <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
 </application>`

Comment: Mixing CODI @ViewAccessScoped and Spring ManagedBeans causing the problem?

Comment: @BalusC Another reason for using `CODI`  `@ViewAccessScoped` was there was no `scope("view")`

Comment: Your annotation in the *faces-config.xml* file shows that you're using Spring handle the managed beans, not JSF nor CDI. *Mixing CODI @ViewAccessScoped and Spring ManagedBeans causing the problem?* Yes

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza If you post an answer I would be happy to accept it. Thanks